# How do I get neovim to automatically return to normal mode when idle?

Tags: neovim, plugin-deoplete

This works fine in vim 8:

```
autocmd CursorHoldI * stopinsert
```

After about 5 seconds or so of inactivity in insert mode it automatically returns to normal mode.

However, in neovim I use the deoplete autocompletion plugin, which is great... except it stops this from working. Any way to have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: Seems to work well for me if I type `:autocmd CursorHoldI * stopinsert` in the Neovim command line. Maybe there is something else in your setup? See [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51) for some guidance on how to isolate the problem.